# Selenium program throws compilation error org.openqa.selenium.internal.Killable cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've created a new Java project using Selenium and Maven. This is the relevant content in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I then created this basic Java program that uses Selenium framework:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "D:\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = null;
        try {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            String baseUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/";

            driver.get(baseUrl);

        } finally {
            driver.close();
        }

    }
}
```

However, I'm getting this compilation error:

> The type org.openqa.selenium.internal.Killable cannot be resolved. It
>   is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Can someone pls suggest where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this dependency from `pom.xml`:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

---

You are using a vesrion 2.45.0 of Selenium java bindings (published on February 2015):

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you examine compile dependencies of the above package: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/2.45.0

you will see that this package depends on `selenium-chrome-driver 2.45.0` package. Maven will resolve this dependency automatically during compilation, so you don't need to declare this package in the `pom.xml`. file.

---

But if you declare this package `selenium-chrome-driver` as a dependency  directly in the `pom.xml` file, using different version (the newest `3.8.1`), then maven will be using this version `3.8.1` instead of `2.45.0` during compilation, and this will cause the error - wrong, incompatibile jar library is used.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! There were few issues even after removing the entries. I solved it by re-creating the relevant packages in local maven repo

Answer (score 1):

Please Check in your POM.XMl file that you might have 2 dependency for "selenium-java" or
"selenium-chrome-driver" dependency for two different version.

Answer (score 1):

I also got same error. If you want to resolve this, follow these steps:

1. Go to the path location of `pom.xml`
2. Right-click and select `Give access to`
3. Click on `Remove access`
4. Click on `Change sharing permission`
5. In the dropdown menu, select `Everyone`
6. For `Permission level`, choose `Read/Write`
7. Save the `XML` file.

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

add this dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```